# Java replace string

Tags: java, mysql

Hi all I a have the following code in my java application

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "countries";
CREATE TABLE "countries" (
  "CNT_ISO2" varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  "CNT_CODEN" int(11) NOT NULL,
  "CNT_NAME" varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  "CNT_NAME_SHORT" varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  "CNT_CONTINENT" int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("CNT_ISO2")
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**using java I want to replace all varchar with another character say text**

**eg:- Both varchar(2) and varchar(50) should be replaced with text**

Thanks......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
stmt.replaceAll("varchar(\\(\\d+\\))?", "text");
```

Comment: Thank u  Dmytro thats working fine ...can u please explain that..?

Comment: Rakhesh, this is replacement by Regular Expression. All the \ signs are needed to escape the special meaning of the parentheses.

Comment: @DmytroChyzhykov It's kind of lame to just copy my answer, don't you feel that way? It's what I call "karma vulture" behavior. The proper way was to **edit** my answer and just add two characters into it. I understand, with your rep still in the low three-digit range, but as you move on, please do mind the rules of conduct.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik. Sorry for that. Nothing personal. I've voted your comment in place.

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution can be as easy as

```
stmt.replaceAll("varchar(\\(\\d+\\))?", "text")
```

Comment: No, .replace takes a char, not a string.  I think you mean `stmt.replaceAll("varchar([0-9]*)", "text");`

Comment: @PaulTomblin Please, do bother to actually [check the Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). But you are right in pointing out that the parenthesized numbers need to be removed.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik. There is a few mistakes in your code. Just double the first and the last `/` symbols.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, unlike you I *did* check the Javadoc.  Why don't you follow the link you posted, and you'll see that the signature for .replace is either `String replace(char oldChar, char newChar)` or `String replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)`.  Neither takes two Strings as an argument.

Comment: @PaulTomblin Oh I see, you did check it, just are unable to understand what you see. Please, for your education, go back to that page and read it more carefully. Especially the part that says "All Implemented Interfaces". Another approach could be to actually **try out** the code I had in my answer and you criticized. See if the compiler gives you any warning: `System.out.println("abc".replace("ab", "ba"));`.

Comment: You are correct.  I missed that String is now a subclass of CharSequence.  My apologies.